# Running Stardog-examples, build issues

Tags: jena, semantic-web, stardog

I'm getting extremely frustrated. I've been trying to learn semantic web programming for the entire weekend and I've gotten no where. Nothing seems to build or work.

I'm new to using maven and gradle but I've followed all the steps.

Trying to build the stardog-example code

https://github.com/clarkparsia/stardog-examples

But when I run the gradle command, it says

"Url to Stardog repository is not defined, Set up the property 'stardogRepo' in gradle.properties.

I can't even find gradle.properties.  Looked everyhere =/ It's not in the gradle folder either.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: FYI, now that Stardog 3 is out, the examples are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, those examples are in flux as we get ready for the Stardog 3 release.

Your best bet is to go back and [check out the 2.2.x version](https://github.com/clarkparsia/stardog-examples/tree/ee40d5cfb88d790402170a1a2e6887a5557cc741) of the examples.

We'll have it finalized for the release or shortly thereafter.